# How did ìritu evolve from digitus?

Tags: etymology, romance-languages

The Latin word for "finger" is `digitus`. In Italian, I assume the "gi" was lost, perhaps via some lenition of the "g" to `*dijitus` and then `j` was lost, giving `*dītus`, or perhaps accusative `*dītum`, whence Italian "dito". What happened in Sicilian though? THe corresponding term is `ìritu`. Could it be that there was a metathesis giving `*giritus` (as happened with `parabola>*paraola>*paraula>*parola>palora`, where `palora` is found [on the Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palora)), and then the "g" was lost? Or is `ìritu` completely unrelated to `digitus`?

> In short, what are the detailed etymologies of Italian `dito` and Sicilian `ìritu`, and are they etymological cognates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meyer-Luebke, [*Romanisches etymologisches Wörterbuch*](https://archive.org/stream/romanischesetymo00meyeuoft#page/206/mode/2up/search/digitus) (1911):

> 2638. **digitus** „Finger".
>
> Rum. *deget*, vegl. *detco*, ital. *dito*, log. *didu*, obwald. *det*, engad. *daint*, bergell. *dant*, friaul. *det*, frz. *doigt*, prov. *det*, katal. *did*, span., portg. *dedo*; mazed. *dzeadit*, maram. *ǧedet*, **siz., kalabr. *yiditu*, *yiritu*,** neap. *yirȩtȩ*; mazed. *dzeadzit*, megl. *zezit*, *zest*, istr.-rum. *žežet*. —
>
> Plur. DIGITA: rum.
> *degete*, ital. *dita*, obwald. *deta*, afrz. *doye*, lyon. *daya* „Fingerbreite", prov. *deda*, vgl. astur. *deda* „Zehe" neben *diu* „Finger". —
>
> Ablt.: röm., abruzz. *ditone*, lomb. *didon* „Daumen" RomF. XIV, 453; gen. *dieta* „Fingerschwamm" GStLLig. IV, 272; engad. *dancler* „Fingerhut" ; frz. *doigtier* „Däumling".

So yes, there was a metathesis of digitus > *giditus > yiditu > (y)iritu

Comment: Out of curiosity, the languages listed are: Romanian, ?? (vegl.), Italian, ?? (log.), ?? (obwald.), Engadina dialect (right?), ?? (bergell.), Friulano, French (right?), Provençal, Catalan, Spanish, Portuguese, Macedonian (right?), ?? (maram.), Sicilian&Calabrian, Neapolitan, Macedonian again, ?? (megl.), Istriot.

Comment: I scanned it, so there are mistakes which I am trying to edit out. Be patient.

Comment: obwald, Engadina and bergell. are dialects of Rhaeto-Romance languages (obwald. is Surselvian in more modern terminology, i could not identify bergell.)

Comment: @MickG **Vegl.** is Vegliot, a dialect of Dalmatian (Veglia = Krk). **Megl.** is Megleno-Romanian, a Romance language spoken on the border of Greece and FYRO Macedonia. **Mazed.** is likely Macedo-Romanian, which is more commonly known as Aromanian, a Romance language spoken throughout the Balkans.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/romanischesetymo00meyeuoft#page/n23/mode/2up/search/digitus : **Log** = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logudorese_dialect (Sardinian). **Bergell** = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val_Bregaglia in Switzerland. **Maram** is not in the index of abbreviations.

Comment: **Maram** is probably Maramureșean, a northern Transylvanian variety of Eastern Romance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maramure%C8%99_dialect

Comment: I found it in his list of Sprachen und Dialekte, p. 1089 https://archive.org/stream/romanischesetymo00meyeuoft#page/1088/mode/2up/search/maram